# Print friendly web resume

Tags: html, css, printing, bootstrap-4

I am trying add a print-friendly feature to a Bootstrap 4 template resume/CV. I would like to reduce the spacing between the sections, when printed. Thus, from the website, can print to PDF and convert to word document.

My website is: https://maschmeyer.ca
My GitHub is: https://github.com/sheldonmaschmeyer/website-sheldon
Modifying resume.min.css, I have a more print-friendly page however, it is not exactly correct. I want to be able to edit the website and, through a printer-friendly rendering, create a PDF and/or Word document. Therefore, less maintaining issues (different versions); Indeed, LinkedIn etc. changes are time consuming enough.

This is what I have done so far:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: Letter portrait;
    margin-top: 1.5cm;
    margin-bottom: 1.5cm;
    margin-left: 1.5cm;
    margin-right: 1.5cm;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  section.resume-section {
    page-break-before: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
```

The @page section moves the date (i.e. Jane 2014 - Jan 2015) from the right-side when displaying, to the bottom of the subsection when printing. This I do not want.
Each section has too much of a space between them, for printing. 
I will attempt to adjust font sizes after fixing the section spacing.
Ideally, I would like to compress the sections, will ignore the last section, 'Services', into two pages when printed.

In Summary, below is a screenshot of a print preview. I want to reduce/remove the section spacing when printing. The section spacing is fantastic when viewing on screen but does not translate to paper The style-sheet I am using is: https://github.com/sheldonmaschmeyer/website-sheldon/blob/master/css/resume.min.css

[Print-Preview in Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ucqf.png)

Comment: Hi! Your question seems a bit broad. Do you have specific questions that you would like answered? For those questions, can you create a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)?

Comment: Does the summary and screenshot link help to clarify?
I tried setting the padding-top and padding-bottom to 0 for @media print section.resume-section but did not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just had to think about it.

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: Letter portrait;
    margin: 0.5cm;
  }
  body {
    padding-top: 6rem!important;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  .m-0,
  .m-0 *,
  .dont-print,
  .dont-print * {
    display: none!important;
  }
  section.resume-section {
    margin-top: -10rem!important;
    padding-top: 0rem!important;
    padding-bottom: 0rem!important;
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
```